# How do I pass the username variable to a third php page?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session, post

1. A user logs on using any username and password (index.php)
2. The form goes for processing in at "login.php"
3. Once logged on, the "login.php" directs the user to "friends.php"

I want to display on the friends.php page, the **exact username** the user entered when he/she initially logged in using the index script.

I tried using sessions and $_POST, but to no success. Please help!

**index.php**

```
<html>


    <body>
            Username: <input type = "text" name = "username"><br>
            Password: <input type = "password" name = "pass_word"><br>
            <input type = "submit" value = "Login"> 
        </form>

    </body>

</html>

<?php

    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    }

?>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) == true) {
        header("Location: friends.php");

    }

?>
```

**friends.php**

```
<?php

    session_start();

    echo $_POST['username'];

?>
```

Comment: Store the user Id in session and don't forget session_start,  using the I'd stored in session retrieve the row for the I'd from user table and display the user name

Comment: `echo $_SESSION['username']` in friends.php instead of `echo $_POST['username'];`

Comment: would suggest using `<form>` tag with `method="post"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your code as it is will give you undefined variables   errors, from what I see there's no form with a POST method, maybe you left that part out.

This is what you need to do

**index.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])){

        header("location:friends.php");
    }

?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="login.php">
            Username: <input type = "text" name = "username"><br>
            Password: <input type = "password" name = "pass_word"><br>
            <input type = "submit" value = "Login" name="loginBtn"> 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

> I can also see that you have tagged `mysql` but you don't have any
>   queries with your code so you will have to do your own queries, just
>   fixing the mistakes you have now.

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$errors = "";
$fields = array("username","pass_word");


if (isset($_POST['loginBtn'])) {

    //check if fields are not empty
    foreach ($fields as $key => $fieldname) {

        if (!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) && empty($_POST[$fieldname])) {

            echo "please enter username and password";
            $errors++;
        }
    }

    if ($errors <= 0) {
        //we have no errors 

        $password = $_POST['pass_word'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];

        //THE DO YOUR QUERIES WHEN THEY ARE SUCCESSFUL THEN


        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        header("location:friends.php");  
    }

}
?>
```

**friends.php**

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])){


        echo $_SESSION['username'];
    }else{

        // THE USER WAS NOT SUPPOSE TO BE HERE DO SOMETHING ABOUT THAT
    }
?>
```

NB: If you will be storing this in a database for passwords, you need to use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` and also use prepared statements in your queries.

Good luck.

Comment: session_start();
 
 $password = $_POST['pass_word'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

Comment: @Masivuye
 what if we place username on the submit button? does it possible?

Answer (score 0):

on the friends.php page do something like the following

```
<?php 

session_start()

if(isset($_SESSION['username']){
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
}
else{
    echo 'username not set';
}

?>
```

I would also recommend using the w3 html validator using this [link](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Session

Something like:

**Form**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
?>
```

**Page friends.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION['username']);
?>
```

?>

Look the doc for more informations: http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 0):

You can set session variable, and share variable with session between web pages.